# EJB 3.0 Singleton with transaction attribute NOT_SUPPORTED and transaction management type BEAN calling method with transaction attribute REQUIRES_NEW

Tags: transactions, ejb

EJB 3.0 Singleton client with transaction attribute NOT_SUPPORTED and transaction management type BEAN calling method with transaction attribute REQUIRES_NEW

```
@Local
@Singleton(name = "MySingleton", mappedName = "MySingleton")
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Lock(LockType.READ)
@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class MySingleton
{
public void call()
{
MyBean myBean = serviceLocator.lookup(MyBean.class);
myBean.transactionalMethod();
}
}

@Remote
@Stateless(mappedName = "MyBean", name = "MyBean")
public class MyBean
{

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public MyObject transactionalMethod(){}


}
```

Comment: The question is how would a call to the method of singleton behave. Will a new transaction be created for the bean method ?

Comment: I am wondering why this question has been upvoted !

Comment: @Leonardo can you please explain the behavior. Will myBean.transactionalMethod run in its own transaction ?

Comment: Yes, you are accessing the EJB trough a `@Remote` interface, so a new transaction will be started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Leonardo, myBean.transactionalMethod will run in its own transaction since we call it via @Remote

Comment: Just for completeness, when you invoke trough a `@remote` interface and you mark your method with `required` or `required_new` a new transaction is always started.